# Writing a Webpack Plugin that splits chunks by file size

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, webpack

I'm currently working on a plugin that would split a single chunk into multiple chunks based on a maximum file size threshold.

For example, consider a workflow of taking 100 JavaScript files and combining them into a single `bundle.js` file with webpack.

My current plugin is rather simple and looks sort of like this (written in coffeescript):

```
CHUNK_SIZE_MODIFIERS = {
    chunkOverhead: 1
    entryChunkMultiplicator: 1
}

module.exports = class
    constructor: (@fileSize) ->

    apply: (compiler) ->
        maxFileSize = @fileSize
        compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) ->
            compilation.plugin('optimize-chunk-assets', (chunks) ->
                chunks.slice().forEach((chunk) ->
                    return if chunk.size(CHUNK_SIZE_MODIFIERS) <= maxFileSize

                    totalChunks = 1
                    currentChunk = createChunk("#{chunk.name}#{totalChunks}")
                    chunk.modules.forEach((module, idx) ->
                        if module.size() + currentChunk.size(CHUNK_SIZE_MODIFIERS) > maxFileSize and currentChunk.modules.length > 0
                            totalChunks++
                            currentChunk = createChunk("#{chunk.name}#{totalChunks}")

                        currentChunk.addModule(module)
                        module.addChunk(currentChunk)
                    )

                    chunk.remove('empty')
                    chunks.splice(chunks.indexOf(chunk), 1)
                )
            )
        )
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't actually seem to work for me, as one of these modules is essentially the module that `__webpack_require__`s all of the others.  This module eventually fails, because it looks for a module ID that exists within a separate chunk now.

I tried using `CommonsChunkPlugin` a bit to see how creating a new chunk would look, but my current implementation doesn't get around the problem mentioned above.  Is there a way to rebuild a chunk once it's been split that would regenerate the mentioned module correctly?  Or something else that I can do once the modules have been split into the new chunk?

Comment: have you tried LimitChunkCountPlugin or MinChunkSizePlugin?

Comment: I've looked into those plugins. Unfortunately, they are more focused on combining two plugins into one, instead of splitting a plugin into more than one. Maybe I'm missing something, though.